# Horizontally aligning list elements with relative divs in them

Tags: html, css

For the past two hours I have been trying to horizontally align an unordered list of card elements.

This is my HTML:

```
  <div id="hand-list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <card></card>
      </li>
      <li>
        <card></card>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
div#hand-list ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    max-width: 170px;
    float: left;
}

div#hand-list ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I just get them vertically stacked all the time?

At a fundamental level, a card is the following (which is just a bit of AngularJS):

```
<div class="card" shift>
    <div class="card-header">
        <h4>{{ user.firstName | limitTo:10 }} {{ user.lastName | limitTo:1 }}.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        {{ user.label }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe it has to do with the structure of a "card." Let me put it in here.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? the cards will stack because you have set a max-width of 170px to the list and it's not enough to hold 2 cards in a single row at 150px each

Comment: Jeez, how dumb of me! I had copied code from another segment of my code which is similar to this and forgot to take out the max-width limitation! Thanks a lot, I guess another observing pair of eyes helps a lot.

Comment: before posting css that doesn't come close to your needs...create a demo in jsfiddle.net, or plunker first...and at least fine tune it as far as you can. Don't need angular either to fine tune basic html layout. Probably should look at css3 properties, like `rotate`